# How to set .htaccess to redirect from a dynamic querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic

I'd like to redirect the following urls:

http://www.domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/

AND

same link as above but with this behind it /?gclid=RANDOM_CHARS
(I cannot post more then two links due to not enough reputation)

TO

http://www.domain.com/?pT=BLAH&sQ=BLAH&CCID=BLAH

I've been playing around in the .htaccess file, but without any luck.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: is `BLAH` available anywhere in original URL?

Comment: Nah, its just numbers. :) Fixed numbers though.

Comment: Can you provide 1 or 2 more examples of `"from" and "to" URLs`

Comment: from: http://www.domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/ and http://www.domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/?gclid=CJKovOK1wbwCFYjLtAodjz0A2A AND http://www.domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/?gclid=CJKovOK1wbwCFYjLtAodFRe4e ALL go to http://www.domain.com/?pT=3&sQ=353&CCID=563653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/[\w-]+/?$ /?pT=3&sQ=353&CCID=563653 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But shouldn't it be something like  domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/[\w-]+/?$ /?pT=3&sQ=353&CCID=563653 [L,R] as the first link is always from that directory?

Comment: My regex will match `domain.com/20,9638,0,26/product-description/` and redirect it to `/?pT=3&sQ=353&CCID=563653`. Is that not what you want, please clarify.